# Duda con arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una duda con arrayList, en el siguiente caso es un proyecto de un centro academico que cuenta con la clase alumno y la clase asignatura.

Necesito matricular un alumno en una asignatura por medio del atributo 'expediente' de la clase 'Alumno' y por medio del atributo 'codigo' de la clase asignatura.

No lo veo claro, necesito otra clase para hacer de puente entre estas dos?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CentroAcademico {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList <Alumno> Alumnos = new  ArrayList <Alumno>();

        ArrayList <Asignatura> Asignaturas = new  ArrayList <Asignatura>();

        boolean salir = false;

        int opcion;

        while (!salir) {

            System.out.println("1. Crear alumno.");
            System.out.println("2. Crear asignatura.");
            System.out.println("3. Matricular alumno.");
            System.out.println("4. Salir");

            try {

                System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
                opcion = sn.nextInt();

                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:

                        crearAlumno(Alumnos);

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        crearAsignatura(Asignaturas);

                        break;
                    case 3:


                        break;

                    case 4:
                        salir = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
                sn.next();
            }       
        }    
    }

    public static void crearAlumno(ArrayList <Alumno> Alumnos){

        Alumno Datos;

        Datos=new Alumno();

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese su Nombre: ");
        Datos.nombre=leer.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese su expediente: ");
        Datos.expediente=leer.nextInt(); 

        Alumnos.add(Datos);

    }

    public static void crearAsignatura(ArrayList <Asignatura> Asignaturas){

        Asignatura Datos;

        Datos=new Asignatura();

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese su codigo: ");
        Datos.codigo=leer.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        Datos.nombre=leer.next(); 

        System.out.println("Ingrese su creditos: ");
        Datos.credito=leer.nextInt(); 

        Asignaturas.add(Datos);

    }

    public static void matricular(){


    }

}
```

Clase Alumno

```
public class Alumno {

int expediente;
String nombre;

public Alumno(int expediente, String nombre) {
    this.expediente = expediente;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Alumno() {
}

public int getExpediente() {
    return expediente;
}

public void setNumExpediente(int numExpediente) {
    this.expediente = numExpediente;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Alumno{" + "numExpediente=" + expediente + ", nombre=" + nombre + '}';
}
}
```

Clase Asignatura

```
public class Asignatura {

int codigo;
String nombre;
int credito;

public Asignatura(int codigo, String nombre, int credito) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.credito = credito;
}

public Asignatura() {
}


public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getCredito() {
    return credito;
}

public void setCredito(int credito) {
    this.credito = credito;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Asignatura{" + "codigo=" + codigo + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", credito=" + credito + '}';
}
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿guardarás la información en una base de datos? Recuerda que en estos casos las `Clases` deberían parecerse a nuestro modelo de datos.

Comment: No, la información la guardo en arrayList.

Comment: Me refiero a **dónde persiste la información**. Un arrayList es para manipular datos, pero cuando cierras el programa esos datos desaparecen si no los guardas en alguna parte. No sé si entiendes a lo que me refiero.

Comment: Es un programa sencillo no necesito que la información se guarde si cierro el programa.

Comment: En ese caso creo que lo correcto sería dotar a la clase `Alumno` de un nuevo miembro del tipo `ArrayList<Asignatura>`, en el cual guardarías todas las asignaturas a las que el alumno esté inscrito.